# Код для проверки активной страницы

Tags: php, html

Данным циклом я вывожу все категории не сайте (http://sellfile.ru/?action=archive&categoryId=18) в виде меню, а затем проверяю активную страницу, если она активна выделяю её. И собственно вопрос, можно ли так писать проверку, можно как то оптимизировать данный код?

```
<?php foreach ( $results['categories'] as $category ) { ?>
<?php 
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url3 = "";
$url5 = $category->id;
$url2 = "/?action=archive&categoryId={$url5}";
if($url == $url2)
{$url3 = "list-group-item active";}
else
{$url3 = "list-group-item";}

?>

<a href="?action=archive&categoryId=<?php echo $category->id?>" class="<?php echo $url3 ?>"><?php echo $category->name?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: > можно как то оптимизировать данный код?

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url3 = "";
    $url5 = $category->id;
    $url2 = "/?action=archive&categoryId={$url5}";

Непосредственно урлом из этого является ничего

    $items = array();
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    foreach ($results['categories'] as $cat) {
        $item = array(
            'category' => $cat,
            'uri' => '/?action=archive&categoryId='.$cat->id,
            'class' => 'list-group-item'
        );
        if ($uri === $item['uri']) {
            $item['class'] .= ' active';
        }
    }

Comment: @Fike спасибо за помощь